# Efficient way to get Image Url in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

Efficient way to get Image Url in magento?

Currently i am using these method

```
$my_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($value['entity_id']); 
$my_product_img = $my_product->getImageUrl();
```

I need a efficient way to load the image url in magento as the above query uses 2 many space and unused queries.

Already tried

```
$my_product_img = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($my_product->getSmallImage());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without full load of product object you can product image url

```
$image = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($value['entity_id']), 'image', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());

if($image){

$my_product_img = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($image);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the full product URL using this:

```
<?php
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($value['entity_id']);
$image = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image');
```

To get the `small_image` or `thumbnail`, you can replace `image` with any of these values.

Comment: I tried this but it also loads 2 many queries. i need some thing which does not load entire catalog/product model and directly fetches it value.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try below code , it may help you

```
echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'media/catalog/product'. $_product->getImage();
```